# How to extend an numpy array with two index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an numpy matrix, for example:

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

Then, I want to use another numpy matrix with indexes to extend the matrix, for example:

```py
idxes = np.array(([0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]) # the indexes matrix
```

The operation is like:

```py
result = a[:, idxes] # this is an wrong expression
```

The result I expected is:

```py
>>result
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [4, 3, 4]])
```

I want to know how to do that.

Comment: The answer is `a[np.arange(len(a))[:,None], idxes]`, I am refraining from posting an answer in case this is a dupe.

Comment: Posting an answer because I couldn't find a duplicate for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to specify the a range for the first (0<sup>th</sup>) axis.

```
a[np.arange(len(a))[:,None], idxes]
```

This intuitively follows the indexing operation, the first row of `idxes` will index into the first row of `a`, the second row of `idxes` will index the second row of `a`, and so on.

Additionally, the dimensions of `arange` array need to be expanded from 1D to 2D because `idxes` is also a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

A fun way `diagonal` + `take`, `diagonal` here make sure you always slice the row index equal to the columns index items , which will return the just like row-wise out put

```
np.diagonal(np.take(a, idxes,1)).T
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [4, 3, 4]])
```

Or

```
np.diagonal(a[:,idxes]).T
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [4, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: Nice answer! Keep in mind that the result of `a[:,idxes]` contains many rows that you won't need as well.

Comment: @coldspeed yep , I notice that ,as I mentioned a fun way :-)

Comment: In my program, the result of `a[:, idxes]` is a very huge matrix, and the run time is very long. So, it is not a perfect way to do this.